# pip doesn't install anything and tells me to upgrade pip

Tags: python, bash, pip, installation, package

So whenever I try to install anything pip throws this error:

```
DEVICE_NAME:~ MY_NAME$ sudo pip install pyautogui
Password:
The directory '/Users/daankoning/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/daankoning/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pyautogui
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/83/89b5adbc37d1bbf7b486a2c1c00e8037e6f801e8c053c4897bb82d9510c6/PyAutoGUI-0.9.36.tar.gz (46kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.3MB/s 
Collecting pymsgbox (from pyautogui)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/65/86379ede1db26c40e7972d7a41c69cdf12cc6a0f143749aabf67ab8a41a1/PyMsgBox-1.0.6.zip
Collecting PyTweening>=1.0.1 (from pyautogui)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/f8/c32a58d6e4dff8aa5c27e907194d69f3b57e525c2e4af96f39c6e9c854d2/PyTweening-1.0.3.zip
Collecting Pillow (from pyautogui)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/df/aa/a25f211a4686f363d8ca5a1752c43a8f42459e70af13e20713d3e636f0af/Pillow-5.1.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (3.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.6MB 3.5MB/s 
Collecting pyscreeze (from pyautogui)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/ec/e625b7c4f496977eafc441cd1f71becc8436a4ff0714263b885d269d866a/PyScreeze-0.1.14.tar.gz
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 has requirement numpy>=1.5, but you'll have numpy 1.8.0rc1 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pymsgbox, PyTweening, Pillow, pyscreeze, pyautogui
  Running setup.py install for pymsgbox ... done
  Running setup.py install for PyTweening ... done
  Running setup.py install for pyscreeze ... done
  Running setup.py install for pyautogui ... done
Successfully installed Pillow-5.1.0 PyTweening-1.0.3 pyautogui-0.9.36 pymsgbox-1.0.6 pyscreeze-0.1.14
You are using pip version 10.0.0b2, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

and when I then type `pip install --upgrade pip` it throws the same error. I've tried reinstalling pip thrice over already and I'm completely out of ideas as to what I can do.

It also does this when I try to install any other package, not jus `pyautogui`.

Please note that this is only on my OSX machine whilst on my PC it works perfectly fine.

Comment: What python install are you using? Default? Homebrew?

Comment: default python version

Comment: @DaanKoning are you referring to the the matplotlib errors?

Comment: I never installed matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always the option downloading a .whl-file and install it with

```
pip install /some-dir/some-file.whl
```

I have the same problems as you have with Py 3.4, so i just use Py 3.5. But I know there is no Version of PyAutoGui for 3.x. You can install this package per wheel, and if it is only this package, this'd be ok... Obviously, it *does* do Pillow...

Comment: When I download the `pyautogui` files it just gives me a folder. Which of these files should I `pip install` or run?